# How to write unix regular expression to select for specific files in a cp for-loop

Tags: regex, bash, for-loop, unix

I've got a directory with a bunch of files. Instead of describing the filenames and extensions, I'll just show you what is in the directory:

```
P01_1.atag  P03_3.tgt   P05_6.src   P08_3.atag  P10_5.tgt
P01_1.src   P03_4.atag  P05_6.tgt   P08_3.src   P10_6.atag
P01_1.tgt   P03_4.src   P06_1.atag  P08_3.tgt   P10_6.src
P01_2.atag  P03_4.tgt   P06_1.src   P08_4.atag  P10_6.tgt
P01_2.src   P03_5.atag  P06_1.tgt   P08_4.src   P11_1.atag
P01_2.tgt   P03_5.src   P06_2.atag  P08_4.tgt   P11_1.src
P01_3.atag  P03_5.tgt   P06_2.src   P08_5.atag  P11_1.tgt
P01_3.src   P03_6.atag  P06_2.tgt   P08_5.src   P11_2.atag
P01_3.tgt   P03_6.src   P06_3.atag  P08_5.tgt   P11_2.src
P01_4.atag  P03_6.tgt   P06_3.src   P08_6.atag  P11_2.tgt
P01_4.src   P04_1.atag  P06_3.tgt   P08_6.src   P11_3.atag
P01_4.tgt   P04_1.src   P06_4.atag  P08_6.tgt   P11_3.src
P01_5.atag  P04_1.tgt   P06_4.src   P09_1.atag  P11_3.tgt
P01_5.src   P04_2.atag  P06_4.tgt   P09_1.src   P11_4.atag
P01_5.tgt   P04_2.src   P06_5.atag  P09_1.tgt   P11_4.src
P01_6.atag  P04_2.tgt   P06_5.src   P09_2.atag  P11_4.tgt
P01_6.src   P04_3.atag  P06_5.tgt   P09_2.src   P11_5.atag
P01_6.tgt   P04_3.src   P06_6.atag  P09_2.tgt   P11_5.src
P02_1.atag  P04_3.tgt   P06_6.src   P09_3.atag  P11_5.tgt
P02_1.src   P04_4.atag  P06_6.tgt   P09_3.src   P11_6.atag
P02_1.tgt   P04_4.src   P07_1.atag  P09_3.tgt   P11_6.src
P02_2.atag  P04_4.tgt   P07_1.src   P09_4.atag  P11_6.tgt
P02_2.src   P04_5.atag  P07_1.tgt   P09_4.src   P12_1.atag
P02_2.tgt   P04_5.src   P07_2.atag  P09_4.tgt   P12_1.src
P02_3.atag  P04_5.tgt   P07_2.src   P09_5.atag  P12_1.tgt
P02_3.src   P04_6.atag  P07_2.tgt   P09_5.src   P12_2.atag
P02_3.tgt   P04_6.src   P07_3.atag  P09_5.tgt   P12_2.src
P02_4.atag  P04_6.tgt   P07_3.src   P09_6.atag  P12_2.tgt
P02_4.src   P05_1.atag  P07_3.tgt   P09_6.src   P12_3.atag
P02_4.tgt   P05_1.src   P07_4.atag  P09_6.tgt   P12_3.src
P02_5.atag  P05_1.tgt   P07_4.src   P10_1.atag  P12_3.tgt
P02_5.src   P05_2.atag  P07_4.tgt   P10_1.src   P12_4.atag
P02_5.tgt   P05_2.src   P07_5.atag  P10_1.tgt   P12_4.src
P02_6.atag  P05_2.tgt   P07_5.src   P10_2.atag  P12_4.tgt
P02_6.src   P05_3.atag  P07_5.tgt   P10_2.src   P12_5.atag
P02_6.tgt   P05_3.src   P07_6.atag  P10_2.tgt   P12_5.src
P03_1.atag  P05_3.tgt   P07_6.src   P10_3.atag  P12_5.tgt
P03_1.src   P05_4.atag  P07_6.tgt   P10_3.src   P12_6.atag
P03_1.tgt   P05_4.src   P08_1.atag  P10_3.tgt   P12_6.src
P03_2.atag  P05_4.tgt   P08_1.src   P10_4.atag  P12_6.tgt
P03_2.src   P05_5.atag  P08_1.tgt   P10_4.src
P03_2.tgt   P05_5.src   P08_2.atag  P10_4.tgt
P03_3.atag  P05_5.tgt   P08_2.src   P10_5.atag
P03_3.src   P05_6.atag  P08_2.tgt   P10_5.src
```

I have a file that is just outside of this directory that I need to copy to all of the files that end with "_1.src" inside the directory.

I'm working with unix in the Terminal app, so I tried writing this for loop, but it rejected my regular expression:

```
for .*1.src in ./ 
> do
> cp ../1.src
> done
```

I've only written regular expressions in Python before and have minimal experience, but I was under the impression that .* would match any combination of characters. However, I got the following error message:

```
-bash: `.*1.src': not a valid identifier
```

I then tried the same for loop with the following regular expression:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*1.src$
```

But I got the same error message:

```
-bash: `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*1.src$': not a valid identifier
```

I tried the same regular expression with and without quotation marks, but it always gives the same 'not a valid identifier' error message.

Comment: You seem to be misinterpreting _regular expressions_ with _pathname expansion trough pattern matching_ (better known as [glob patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29)). The difference is, _regular expressions_ are used in commands or functions for pattern matching in text. _Globbing_ is used by shells for matching file and directory names using wildcards. The syntax of the latter depends on the shell. They are far from the same. What you try to do is use a regex to match a file or directory, i.e. the wrong one.

Comment: Oh, wow. Thanks a ton. Feeling super ignorant here. Did not realize that at all. Thanks. Assuming I should take this question down then, right?

Comment: No, why? If another person has a similar question, this information is useful for that person.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone; this is what ended up working:

```
for x in `echo ./P[0-9]*_1.src`
> do
> cp ../1.src "$x"
> done
```

This loop allowed me to copy the contents of the one file to all of the files in the subdirectory that ended with "_1.src"

Answer (score 1):

Tested on Bash 4.4.12, the following is possible:

```
$ for i in ./*_1.src; do echo "$i" ; done
```

This will echo every file ending with `_1.src` to the screen, thus moving it will be possible as well.

```
$ mkdir tmp
$ for i in ./*_1.src; do mv "$i" tmp/.; done
```

I've tested with the following data:

```
$ touch P{1,2}{0,1,2}_{0..6}.{src,tgt,atag}
$ ls
P10_0.atag  P10_5.src   P11_3.tgt   P12_2.atag  P20_0.src   P20_5.tgt   P21_4.atag  P22_2.src
P10_0.src   P10_5.tgt   P11_4.atag  P12_2.src   P20_0.tgt   P20_6.atag  P21_4.src   P22_2.tgt
P10_0.tgt   P10_6.atag  P11_4.src   P12_2.tgt   P20_1.atag  P20_6.src   P21_4.tgt   P22_3.atag
P10_1.atag  P10_6.src   P11_4.tgt   P12_3.atag  P20_1.src   P20_6.tgt   P21_5.atag  P22_3.src
P10_1.src   P10_6.tgt   P11_5.atag  P12_3.src   P20_1.tgt   P21_0.atag  P21_5.src   P22_3.tgt
P10_1.tgt   P11_0.atag  P11_5.src   P12_3.tgt   P20_2.atag  P21_0.src   P21_5.tgt   P22_4.atag
P10_2.atag  P11_0.src   P11_5.tgt   P12_4.atag  P20_2.src   P21_0.tgt   P21_6.atag  P22_4.src
P10_2.src   P11_0.tgt   P11_6.atag  P12_4.src   P20_2.tgt   P21_1.atag  P21_6.src   P22_4.tgt
P10_2.tgt   P11_1.atag  P11_6.src   P12_4.tgt   P20_3.atag  P21_1.src   P21_6.tgt   P22_5.atag
P10_3.atag  P11_1.src   P11_6.tgt   P12_5.atag  P20_3.src   P21_1.tgt   P22_0.atag  P22_5.src
P10_3.src   P11_1.tgt   P12_0.atag  P12_5.src   P20_3.tgt   P21_2.atag  P22_0.src   P22_5.tgt
P10_3.tgt   P11_2.atag  P12_0.src   P12_5.tgt   P20_4.atag  P21_2.src   P22_0.tgt   P22_6.atag
P10_4.atag  P11_2.src   P12_0.tgt   P12_6.atag  P20_4.src   P21_2.tgt   P22_1.atag  P22_6.src
P10_4.src   P11_2.tgt   P12_1.atag  P12_6.src   P20_4.tgt   P21_3.atag  P22_1.src   P22_6.tgt
P10_4.tgt   P11_3.atag  P12_1.src   P12_6.tgt   P20_5.atag  P21_3.src   P22_1.tgt   P10_5.atag  
P11_3.src   P12_1.tgt   P20_0.atag  P20_5.src   P21_3.tgt   P22_2.atag
```

Comment: You should quote the expansion of `$i`, or it'll fail for files with blanks or glob characters in them.

Comment: I always forget the spaces because I don't use them in filenames. It's harmless within this example, tho :p

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, my previous answer didn't work. But this seems to:

```
$ for x in `echo ./P[01][012]_1.src`; do echo "$x"; done
./P01_1.src
./P02_1.src
```

So, when you run this `echo` alone, this pattern gets expanded into *many names*:

```
$ echo ./P[01][012]_1.src  # note that the 'regex' is not enclosed in quotes
./P01_1.src ./P02_1.src
```

And then you can iterate over these names in a loop.

BTW, as noted in the comments, you don't even need that `echo`, so you can plug the pattern right into the loop:

```
for x in ./P[01][012]_1.src; do echo "$x"; done
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I need to only iterate over the files that end with "_1.src". In other words, there are three files called "P01_1" that have three different extensions, and I need to only grab the .src files. At the same time, I don't want the "P01_2.src" file, etc.

Comment: @shadowplumber, well, it's not too hard to modify this code to do that: try `"./P[01][012]_1\.src"` as the regex.

Comment: This doesn't do what you think it does. You are relying on word-splitting and pathname expansion of unprotected variables when you use `echo $x`. It just seems to work in this case. The `for` loop iterates just once! Try it for filenames with spaces. Furthermore, you can't use regular expressions like that, you are actually using just normal file globs. So `\.` will literally match two characters ```\``` and `.`.

Comment: @mickp, when I run this script with the escaped dot it outputs `./P01_1.src ./P02_1.src`, and these file names definitely don't have backslashes in them. EDIT: Yeah, when I `echo "$x"`, it prints the literal regex.

Comment: `\`echo ./P[01][012]_1.src\`` is the same as just `./P[01][012]_1.src` here, except that it's subject to word splitting.

Comment: @ForceBru Thanks, that did the trick: ```for x in `echo ./P[0-9]*_1.src`; do echo "$x"; done
./P01_1.src
./P02_1.src
./P03_1.src
./P04_1.src
./P05_1.src
./P06_1.src
./P07_1.src
./P08_1.src
./P09_1.src
./P10_1.src
./P11_1.src
./P12_1.src```

Comment: @ForceBru Now, are all of those file names stored in a variable called "x"?

Comment: @shadowplumber, yes, one at a time

Comment: @ForceBru Ok, that makes sense. I can see that when I run ```echo "$x"```, it only prints the name of the last file ```./P12_1.src```. But I don't understand then how I can iterate over that if it only contains the path/filename of the one file.

Comment: @shadowplumber, the loop iterates over all these file names. Just replace `echo "$x"` with your code that copies stuff to `"$x"`.

Comment: @ForceBru Ah, duh. I did just that after asking you (sorry for thinking out loud), and it worked! Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you're using this solution, change `echo` to `ls`: `for x in $(ls ./P[01][0-2]_1.src); do echo "$x"; done`. Otherwise it's possible you're copying non-existent files, which can cause some bugs.

Comment: @Bayou That's even worse than `echo`. The proper way is simply `for x in ./P[01][0-2]_1.src; do` – this will expand only to existing files.

Comment: @BenjaminW, hence the 'if', but I will argue that `ls` is better than `echo`. (Read the lesser evil).

Comment: @Bayou `echo ./P[01][0-2]_1.src` uses the same pattern expansion as `ls ./P[01][0-2]_1.src`. Neither `echo` nor `ls` do the expansion, it's the shell itself. Not sure I understand what's better about using `ls`.

Comment: @BenjaminW, with `echo` you have the possibility the script tries to copy a non-existing file in the for loop. A script that uses `set -e` or some other exit code error handling would cause the script to abort. That will not happen with `ls`, because that command returns existing files.

Comment: @Bayou If I try to `ls` a non-existing file (which happens if nothing matches my glob and I haven't set `shopt -s nullglob`), then `ls` errors as well. But really, both `echo` and `ls` in command substitutions are an anti-pattern for this use case, so there isn't much merit to discussing which of the bad solutions is worse, in my opinion.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Haven't thought about that :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if your goal is something other than

> "overwrite many existing files sharing a common suffix with the contents of a single file"

```
find /path/to/dest_dir -type f -name "*_1.src" |xargs -n1 cp /path/to/source_file
```

Note that without the `-maxdepth 1` option, `find` will recurse through your destination directory.